# How can I have a multiple line Label in a PieChart in AChartEngine?

Tags: android, charts, newline, achartengine, pie-chart

I have a pie chart using AChartEngine that I'm very happy with. I've chosen to style it without a Legend and with Labels (the text connected to its corresponding Pie wedge with a little line) formatted like "Example Data Point - 25%"

I get this Label string via:

```
mSeries.add(name + " - " + Double.toString(value), value);
```

But often the name is too long so the value doesn't display. I get "...". Since the **value is important**, I want to put it on a new line so it will always show.

*I'm picturing Labels that look something like:*

Short Name 
10%

Too Long of A Na...
25%

*Also fine:*

Too Long of A
Name 
25%

*Or:*

Too Long of A
Name - 25%

If I could wrap long names to new lines, that would be even better! But I really am mostly concerned with getting the **Value to always display**.

I tried to add a new line with **\n** or System.getProperty("line.separator") but the PieChart still renders the Label as one line. The \n is not getting displayed as text, it's like it's not even there. According to other Questions, this supposedly works on other Chart types, but no one is claiming it works for Pies, which it doesn't seem to based on my efforts.

I've also played with other rendering options built into AChartEngine. Such as 'setDisplayValues(true)', which puts the values right over the pie wedges. I don't like how that looks, as my pie has some tiny wedges, so the values get rendered on top of each other.

**Any insight on how I can make the Labels on AChartEngine PieChart multi-line (or any other way to force the value to display) would be very appreciated! Thank you so much to anyone who can help!**

Comment: Have anybody gotten any possible solution besides below?

Answer (score 1):

It's not what I really wanted, but since a few months have gone by, I've come up with an alternative. For posterity, I will leave it here as an answer to my own question but not accept it in case someone out there does someday share a real solution.

Since I couldn't find a way to ensure that the labels on my pie chart always showed percent values, I have the info Toast when a wedge is clicked. Here is the simple enough code:

```
    private void addPieClickListeners(final GraphicalView mChartView){
    mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

            if (seriesSelection == null) {
                // Do Nothing, Possible Toast:
                // Toast.makeText(context,"No chart element was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, 
                        Integer.toString((int)Math.round(seriesSelection.getValue())) +
                        "% " + 
                        mSeries.getCategory(seriesSelection.getPointIndex()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I call this method, along with my other functions to set up my Pie Chart, in onCreateView(), since this is in a Fragment.

Cheers.

Comment: @BugsHappen Thanks. Though as a heads up, I'm planning on probably moving from AChartEngine to Google Charts (https://developers.google.com/chart/). I haven't started to be able to say if one is empirically better than the other.

Comment: but you can't use Google Charts offline, can you?

Comment: @BugsHappen Oh maybe you're right! I had only marked it as something to look into, like I said hadn't started. My testers get a lot of crashes having to do with AChartEngine, so I'm in the market for a better alternative.